# Edit text below the display pic in about.me profile?

Tags: about-me

How to edit the text that comes below the display pic after your name. As demarcated in the pic. (Pixellated only to highlight the area).

[image]

What is that line of text technically called? I tried editing the "bio". But that changes the text below the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to edit the text that comes below the display pic after your name.

That part is auto generated using your `Details`.
To make changes you would need to edit by clicking the gear icon at the top right corner and under `Details` update your `Location`, `Interests` etc.

[image: How to edit the text that comes below the display pic after your name in about.me profile.]